# Search with TypeORM works partially but doesn't return all relations

Tags: postgresql, search, filter, typeorm

I have my entities like this:

```
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, { onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user-products',
    joinColumn: { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'productId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  products?: Product[];
}
```

and

```
@Entity({ name: 'product' })
@Unique(['name'])
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;


  @ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.products, { onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  users?: User[];
}
```

and

```
@Entity('user-products')
export class UserProducts {
  @PrimaryColumn('uuid', { name: 'userId' })
  userId: string;

  @PrimaryColumn('uuid', { name: 'productId' })
  productId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.products, { onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' }])
  users: User[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Product /*, product => product.users*/, { onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: 'productId', referencedColumnName: 'id' }])
  products: Product[];
}
```

When I query the db, I do this:

```
this.myRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'userProducts')
```

All is working good so far. But when I add a search query like:

```
this.userRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'userProducts')
      .where(`userProducts.name ilike '%${mySearchValue}%'`)
```

I still get the correct results, but if the user has more than one product, it only returns the user with that particular product, and I want the return result to still have all the products inside. So for example, let's say I have 3 users

```
{
   "id": "user_1_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_1_id",
         "name": "product_1",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_3_id",
         "name": "product_3",
      },
   ],
},
{
   "id": "user_2_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_3_id",
         "name": "product_3",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_4_id",
         "name": "product_4",
      },
   ],
},
{
   "id": "user_3_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_5_id",
         "name": "product_5",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_6_id",
         "name": "product_6",
      }
   ],
}
```

and I search for product_2. The result will be

```
{
   "id": "user_1_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
   ],
},
{
   "id": "user_2_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
   ],
}
```

but I want it to be:

```
{
   "id": "user_1_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_1_id",
         "name": "product_1",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_3_id",
         "name": "product_3",
      },
   ],
},
{
   "id": "user_2_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "product_2_id",
         "name": "product_2",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_3_id",
         "name": "product_3",
      },
      {
         "id": "product_4_id",
         "name": "product_4",
      },
   ],
}
```

sort of like a filter method would run. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever come across this, I found the answer, and it broke my brain. Here it is:

```
const result: SelectQueryBuilder<User> = this.userRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'userProducts')
      .where((qb: SelectQueryBuilder<User>) => {
        const productSubQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('user-products.userId')
          .from('user-products', 'user-products')
          .leftJoin('product', 'p', 'p.id = user-products.productId')
          .where('p.name ILIKE :productName', { productName: `%${mySearchValue}%`})
          .getQuery();

        return `user.id IN ${productSubQuery}`;
      });

const final: User[] = await result.getMany();
```